# How can I queue more than 10 Miis?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza, streetpass

With the September 2016 update, the Streetpass Mii Plaza is said to be able to hold 100 Miis in the queue, as opposed to the maximum of 10 it could before, as long as the user has purchased the Premium update.

I do have the Premium update, but the Plaza seems to still have a maximum of 10 Miis in a queue at one time. It filled up and wouldn't accept any more until I "welcomed" them.

A new icon has also appeared and selecting it says that I can have people wait in there but there is no indication about how I could do this.

How does the new maximum of 100 Miis work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you receive new Miis through Streetpass you simply have to press the purple arrow icon on the right, then you should have a menu with 3 choices:

- **Keep playing**, to remain in the plaza and play with the current Miis
- **Go to the gate**, to receive new Miis just arrived
- **Add to the queue**, to add new Miis in the queue
  <sub>(or something like that, my plaza is not in English)</sub>

Next time you select **Go to the gate** you'll receive another bunch of 10 Miis (at maximum).

It's important to note that, if you receive a Mii through Streepass that is currently in your queue, the new Mii will overwrite the one waiting in queue, avoiding duplicates.